# Python Function Returning Decimal Precision

Tags: python-2.7, precision

I have a function which I want to return a decimal number 1.0000 [not a string], how can I do this without using NUMPY or SCIPY?  No matter what I do, it returns it as 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking for [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) package:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 6
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.142857')
>>> getcontext().prec = 28
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
```

Answer (score 0):

The precision of Python's floats is about 16 digits, no matter how you write them. `1.0` is the same number as `1.0000`. The difference is not in number, but in number-to-string conversion involved in display. Thus, the only way to do what you want is to, as you say, convert it to a string explicitly under your terms: `"{:.4f}".format(1.0)`.